# Alt-Tab stopped working after upgrade to QQ / 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, compiz, shortcut-keys, keyboard

I recently upgraded from PP to QQ which broke the ability to switch between running applications by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> which is such a showstopper I never believed could ever be.

The affected host is a ThinkPad X61s. I'm not quite sure if this is of any relevance but I think Unity/Compiz is running on LLVM - not even sure if this statement makes any sense at all.

So until now I tried several countermeasures in any combination imaginable to tame that beasty behaviour - running out of ideas as of now after having tried every hint I could find:

- bound, unbound and rebound the `Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Navigation/Switch applications` key over and over again
- massive amount of `reboots`
- activated, deactivated, reactivated switchers and set, unset, reset plugins and their key bindings - even other ones as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - in `ccsm` under

  - `Unity Plugin`
  - Window Mgmt - `Application switcher` and `Static application switcher`
- deactivated <kbd>Alt</kbd> as a hotkey for the `HUD`
- even switching `keyboard layouts`

All to no avail which led me here: any ideas, any Ubuntu one?

It may be worth mentioning that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys themselves are working as shown by `xev`. I can access the menu, too. What makes me wonder is the fact that I can get the HUD by tapping <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> but not by using <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> (so I tried removing the HUD key binding which as stated didn't work). App switching itself is not possible using either <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

This highly unwanted behaviour is the same using the internal keyboard as well as my bluetooth one.